# Mixmonitor command is not working in asterisk dialplan

Tags: asterisk, audio-recording, ivr

I have created a dialplan which on getting call from certain extention forward it and dial another number and then record their call using mixmonitor

```
exten => s,n,Mixmonitor(/var/www/html/recordings/answered/${DID}_${FROM}_${ANSWER}.wav)
```

but after farwading call it donot record anything in my folder created
Am i missing something,do i have to enable anything to make it work
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

1) check permission. Asterisk usualy run under asterisk user and not able write to folder owned by apache or root.

2) check file path exist.

3) if not help, enable debug on consoel and see what happens. For that you need add debug in /etc/asterisk/logger.conf to console=> line, do in asterisk consoel "core set debug 5".

Comment: how to check the permission

Comment: ls -l  /var/www/html/recordings/